# Live bindings between the view and model in ASP.NET MVC like in meteor.js/derby.js

Tags: asp.net-mvc, node.js, asp.net-mvc-4, meteor, derbyjs

I'm building my application with ASP.NET MVC, and I wonder, is there any easy way to make live bindings between the view and model?

For instance, if we take a look at meteor.js or derby.js frameworks for node.js, it comes right out of the box, and you need absolutely nothings for this. But is there any libs or approach to make it easy in ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: There is one great library for doing bindings and it could be easily used with any backend.
Please take a look at : [RactiveJS](http://www.ractivejs.org/)

Comment: Learn RactiveJS by example : http://learn.ractivejs.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller passes the model to the View and the View displays itself using the Model. Javascript frameworks use client-side models and Knockout.js is an excellent framework for such a binding.

But, if you want live updates, then you need a Server framework, [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) is a good framework to establish such bindings.